# How to upgrade Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 patches without a subscription?

Tags: rhel, upgrade

How can I upgrade my Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 patches without subscription?

Error message :

> This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Comment: May bee too late for an upgrade. The current version is `6.9` . But you can try by migrating the repo to the free version, "Redhat CentOS 6.9" https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

> If all of your subscriptions expire and you have no other active
>   subscriptions in your organization, you retain the right to use the
>   software under the applicable license terms. However, your entire
>   environment will no longer receive any of the subscription benefits,
>   including:
>
> - The latest certified software versions.
> - Security errata and bug fixes ...

https://www.redhat.com/en/about/subscription-model-faq

Comment: Hi dsstorefile, thanks for your information. I just found out there is a solution for this error and some of the users were tested good. https://saifulaziz.com/2014/02/26/howto-install-redhat-package-with-yum-command-without-rhn/

Comment: @lswong the linked “solution” won’t allow you to upgrade, and you won’t get any security fixes and such like.

Comment: @StephenKitt noted, thanks for your information.